# ¿Por qué el formato de los códigos no tienen las líneas numeradas?

Tags: característica-nueva

Me gusta el formato que stack overflow le ponen a los códigos en las preguntas, solo que no entiendo porque no enumerar las líneas:

```bash
cd "/users/"   #Formato actual linea 1
mkdir "Daniel" # ** ** ** 2
cat > "hola mundo.bash" # ** ** ** 3
... echo Hola mundo. # ** ** ** 4
... cd "/users/" # ** ** ** 5
... rmdir -p "Daniel" # ** ** ** 6
[CRTL-C] # ** ** ** 7 Combinación de la tecla control+c
sh "/users/daniel/hola mundo.bash" # ** ** ** 8
```

Y lo que me gustaría es algo como esto:

```cpp
1| cd "/users/"
2| mkdir "Daniel"
3| cat > "hola mundo.bash"
4| ... echo Hola mundo.
5| ... cd "/users/"
6| ... rmdir -p "Daniel"
7| [CRTL-C] #Combinación de la tecla control+c
8| sh "/users/daniel/hola mundo.bash"
```

Así para cuando una pregunta diga **me sale que en la línea 8 no se consigue la ruta del archivo pero si claramente yo cree el archivo, ¿Que puedo hacer?** uno pueda ver con un simple vistazo la línea 8 y le diga la respuesta **Lo que pasa es que en bash se distingue mayúsculas y minúsculas y en la ruta pusiste en la línea 8, el nombre "/users/daniel/hola mundo.bash" está en minúscula, pero cuando creaste la carpeta en la línea 2 le pusiste en el nombre una letra mayúscula "/users/Daniel/hola mundo.bash"**

Pero que también sea opcional, porque cuando el código es demasiado largo y se da un enlace al archivo puede confundir la numeración de las líneas actual con la del archivo.

Realmente no es muy importante para responder a las preguntas, pero creo que los códigos en las preguntas se verían mejor con ello.

Comment: Es una propuesta interesante. Normalmente copiamos fragmentos del código a las preguntas y respuestas. Digamos que en una pregunta digo que "en la línea 324 tengo un problema" e incluyo el código desde la línea 320 a la 330. La numeración en la publicación empezará desde el 1 y no del 320. Así que no coincidirán los números y seguirá siendo imposible ver directamente cuál es esa línea. ¿No crees que lo hará más confuso?

Comment: @Mateo Si... es lo malo, también hay personas que ponen todo el código en la pregunta.

Comment: Usualmente copio y pego el código de la pregunta para tratar de reproducir el problema, y tener que eliminar la numeración de linea sería bastante fastidioso. Aunque visualmente la propuesta se ve interesante, habría que definir la forma en que al copiar el código no me incluya dicha numeración. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: ¿Por qué el formato de los códigos no tiene la opción "Copiar-al-Portapapeles"?

Comment: @Mateo. Numerar las líneas sería conveniente para referirse a ellas en los comentarios y respuestas.

Comment: Me agrada la propuesta, ayudaría mucho para las explicaciones tanto en respuestas como preguntas ;)

Comment: solo es viable para un tipo de codigo snipped avanzado que no tenga que ver con html+javascript+CSS seria un metodo snipped adecuado para c#, C++, php, python otros lenguajes, esto puede ser agregado con una extencion si mas no me equivoco.

Comment: Existe algo parecido aqui: https://www.prowaretech.com/articles/current/javascript/add-line-numbers-to-preformatted-text#!

Comment: tendria que implementar webscraping a los sitios con post de esSO y no creo que SO este de acuerdo ...

Comment: Cool. Me gusta. Sí que sí.